# Amazon DynamoDb: How to implement putIfAbsent?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I need the implementation of the `Map.putIfAbsent(K key, V value)` for the DynamoDb:

```
/**
 * If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped
 * to {@code null}) associates it with the given value and returns
 * {@code null}, else returns the current value.
 *
 * @implSpec
 * The default implementation is equivalent to, for this {@code
 * map}:
 *
 * <pre> {@code
 * V v = map.get(key);
 * if (v == null)
 *     v = map.put(key, value);
 *
 * return v;
 * }</pre>
```

So far I have this query:

```
    Item oldItem = this.table.updateItem(
            new UpdateItemSpec()
                    .withPrimaryKey(KEY, key)
                    .withAttributeUpdate(
                            new AttributeUpdate(VALUE)
                                    .put(value))
                    .withExpected(
                            new Expected(KEY)
                                    .notExist())
                    .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_OLD))
            .getItem();
```

But in a case of *exists* I get `ConditionalCheckFailedException`.

Looks like this exception is always thrown when any condition is evaluated to `false`.

I understand that I can *catch* that exception and perform additional `getItem()`, but I'd really to do everything in a single atomic request.

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Comment: My solution is like this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/aws/metadata/DynamoDbMetadataStore.java#L269

Answer (score 1):

I think you may not be able to achieve the above mentioned functionality using DynamoDB low level API without using multiple API calls.

If you use DynamoDB high level API i.e. DynamoDBMapper, the `save()` method on this class has this functionality.

[DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#save-T-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBSaveExpression-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-)

**Save behavior:-**

> UPDATE (default) : UPDATE will not affect unmodeled attributes on a
> save operation and a null value for the modeled attribute will remove
> it from that item in DynamoDB. Because of the limitation of updateItem
> request, the implementation of UPDATE will send a putItem request when
> a key-only object is being saved, and it will send another updateItem
> request if the given key(s) already exists in the table.
>
> UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES : Similar to UPDATE except that it ignores
> any null value attribute(s) and will NOT remove them from that item in
> DynamoDB. It also guarantees to send only one single updateItem
> request, no matter the object is key-only or not.
>
> CLOBBER : CLOBBER
> will clear and replace all attributes, included unmodeled ones,
> (delete and recreate) on save. Versioned field constraints will also
> be disregarded. Any options specified in the saveExpression parameter
> will be overlaid on any constraints due to versioned attributes.

Comment: > and it will send another updateItem request if the given key(s) already exists in the table.

So, looks like there is a couple requests as well. More over I really don't want to use some higher level mapping API to introduce extra overhead to my simple solution. But thanks anyway for the answer, even if it doesn't meet my requirements!